# Retrieving online server databases by keys

Tags: java, database, arraylist, enums

As a intermediate Java student I have a question regarding retrieving single data pieces with a key from a larger document, uploaded online.

My idea is to create enum objects (public static final) and associate one ArrayList to each of enums in its constructor. All of the enums (with arrayLists) would then be uploaded onto the single larger online server database.

My wish is that every enum would serve as a key to retrieve appropriate (associated) arrayList in such document; meaning I would only like to retrieve arrayList one in a time (based on the enum as a key) and not the (whole) document itself. I would then like to add or remove elements from given arrayList and upload them back online.

How can I do that in the most effective fassion possible?

Thank you for your help and have a nice day :D

Comment: This is [not a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but maybe it helps if you search for "nosql database".

Comment: how can I make it better? What is not clear about it?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). The question is too broad to be answered here. Please post the specific part you are having problems with.

Comment: If you want to use an enum type to refer to a list then use the excellent `EnumMap` which is part of Java (since Java 5). You can then declare a `Map<MyEnumType, List<MyListContentsType>>` and initialise it with `new EnumMap(MyEnumType.class)`. As for having the content of a collection automatically synchronizing with a remote server, that's a rather broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my understanding and Assuming you want to use Enum and Arralyslist and store the Arralylist Object in Database.Try following below

You can simply create list from array like this:

```
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList(SomeEnum.values());
```

Note :- Using JDBC API you can Connect to the DB and Insert the ArrayList Object using Insert query in the Database.